# Understanding contracts and Liskov Substitution principle

Tags: design-patterns, liskov-substitution-principle

Consider the diagram :

[image]

Collection - an abstract class with the common part of all the others: abstract functions
that put an integer in a collection and check whether the collection is empty.

Bag  - a class that implements the collection as a hash, where you can find elements easily.
Each element may appear more than once

I need to determine if this inheritance relationship maintain the Liskov Substitution principle.

So, i start with check if the signatures of the function are the same and they are. (put() and isEmpty()). 
After that, i check if the methods contracts of the two are the same, but can i have contracts to abstract class? i can't 'create' it.
if they are, it's enough to say that these two class maintain the LSP?
or something else is needed?

Comment: I know that "contract" has a special meaning in the context of software design. Regarding the LSP (and given that this is not just a homework question) I would look at it from a pragmatic point of view: What do you expect when you call `Collection.put()`? What do you expect when you call `Bag.put()`? Is this coherent? What about `isEmpty()`?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi yes i understand.  Collection and Bag behaves the same with these two methods, so they are maintain the LSP. If, for example Bag.put() was doin something else, lets say put 3 time what you gave it, then it violate the LSP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Software Engineering.SE, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

The [Liskov Substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is one of the 5 basic principles for good object-oriented design (AKA SOLID):

- **S**(RP): [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- **O**(CP): [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)
- **L**(SP): [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)
- **I**(SP): [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)
- **D**(IP): [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

The principle stated by Barbara Liskov says that *Functions that use pointers of references to base classes must be able to use objects of derived classes without knowing it*. It is a good design principle because when a function does not conform to the LSP, then it must know all the possible derivatives of the base class.

The importance of this principle becomes obvious when you consider the consequences of violating it. Let's make an example. Suppose we are developing a program dealing with shapes. We have created the class Rectangle and, when designing class Square, we think natural of inheriting from class Rectangle:

[image: example of Liskov violation]

Using C++ we would write:

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
        virtual void SetWidth(const double w) {width_=w;}
        virtual void SetHeight(const double h) {height_=h;}
        virtual double GetHeight() const {return height_;}
        virtual double GetWidth() const {return width_;}
private:
        double width_;
        double height_;
};

class Square : public Rectangle
{
public:
        virtual void SetWidth(const double w) {
            Rectangle::SetWidth(w);
            Rectangle::SetHeight(w);
        }
        virtual void SetHeight(const double h) {
            Rectangle::SetWidth(w);
            Rectangle::SetHeight(h);
        }
};

void function (Rectangle& r)
{
        r.SetWidth(5);
        r.SetHeight(4);
        assert(r.GetWidth() * r.GetHeight()) == 20);
}
```

As it is clear from the example, the assertion (and the Liskov project) is violated due to the fact that the Rectangle has a property (independency of the size of height and weight) which does not hold for a Square.

To answer your question, you should reason about properties that hold for the base class but not for the derived classes. If the interface is well designed (as it seems), you won't find any and you'll be able of substituting the base class with any derived class.

Comment: Please give an example: How would you reason about the classes, especially about `Collection`?

Comment: @Claudio : I found 2 **typos**: 
`virtual void SetHeight(const double h) {height_=w;}` must be `virtual void SetHeight(const double h) {height_=h;}`;

also `virtual void SetHeight(const double h)` on Square is not setting the `h` parameter.

Comment: @Lorenzo: I've fixed the typos, thank you.

Comment: @Claudio my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, IMHO, with the `Square` class is that is breaking the `Rectangle`'s contract:

- For `Rectangle` the `Width` and `Height` properties are independent, so if you change one the other stays as before
- `Square` is violating this contract by changing both properties in each setter
- If we pass a `Square` to a code expecting a `Rectangle` and counting on the premise that `Width` and `Height` are not related then we have a problem

Also we are violating the **History rule** (see Wikipedia's article [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). Ass odd as it sounds I'll remove the inheritance relationship between these classes and introduce a `Shape` base class, for those tow is hard to stick to the LS principle.